# How to change labels on the x axis of a bar plot from numbers to text?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm trying to make a bar plot using Plots.jl and the GR backend and wanted to ask how to make the x axis display text labels rather than numbers. Basically this is what I'm doing:

```
using Plots; gr()
data = [1,2,3]
labels = ["one","two","three"]

bar(data, legend=false)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: example bar plot]

How do I display my labels ("one", "two", "three"), instead of "1 2 3" on the x axis?

Thanks!

Comment: The way to do this is by passing the labels as the "x" values: `bar(labels, data)`.  However this has been an open issue for the GR backend which I recently implemented.  If you're willing to help test for bugs, this should work on the dev branch: `Pkg.checkout("Plots","dev")`

Comment: Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer (thanks Tom!) is to pass the labels as x values (currently only possible on the dev branch):

```
Pkg.checkout("Plots","dev")
using Plots
gr()

data = [1,2,3]
labels = ["one","two","three"]

bar(labels, data, legend=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Plots` version `v1.38.0`, one can do it by specifying the labels in the optional keyword argument `xticks`:

```
data = [1,2,3]
labels = ["one","two","three"]

bar(
  data,
  legend=false,
  xticks=(1:length(data), labels)
)
```

[image]